# c++ boost regex how to list all matched element?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have an problem, for example I have an input String "[1][2][3]" and should have the output "[1]" "[2]" "[3]" , I tried but it does not work well, my code is just like :

```
//My code 
const std::string strTypeName = "[1][2][3]";
std::vector<std::string> result;
boost::smatch mat;

boost::regex reg("(\\[[0-9]*\\])");
if (boost::regex_match(strTypeName, mat, reg, boost::format_all))
{
    for (boost::smatch::size_type index = 0; index < mat.size(); ++index)
    {
        result.push_back(mat[index]);
    }
}

who can tell me what is the matter with it, It will be great of help !
```

Comment: From the [first linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269325/boost-regex-not-working-as-expected-in-my-code): *The algorithms regex_search and regex_match make use of match_results to report what matched; the difference between these algorithms is that regex_match will only find matches that consume all of the input text, where as regex_search will search for a match anywhere within the text being matched.*.

Comment: And from [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665981/boost-c-regex-how-to-return-all-matches), you need to use `boost::sregex_token_iterator` to get all the matches in a string.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew   ok thank very much ! it works well now !